# jsp - error for not correctly use JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

i have this method in my class conexion

```
public ArrayList<Comuna> getComunas()
{
    ConexionBd();
    try {
        comunas = new ArrayList<Comuna>();
        resultado = consulta.executeQuery("select * from comuna");
        while(resultado.next())
        {
            comunas.add(new Comuna(resultado.getInt("com_id"),resultado.getInt("pro_id"),resultado.getString("com_nombre")));
        }
        CerrarConexionBd();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return comunas;
}
```

I'm trying to put the value here

```
<c:set var="variable" value="${Conexion.getComunas}"></c:set>
```

and display the value with this

```
<select class="form-control" id="comuna" name="comuna">
                        <c:forEach var="comunas" items="${variable} " >
                            <option value="${comunas.com_id}">${comunas.com_nombre}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                        </select>
```

I get this error `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException` : The class `'java.lang.String'` does not have the property 'com_id'

```
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:229)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:206)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:317)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:85)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:1026)
    at org.apache.jsp.formulario_005fempresa_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(formulario_005fempresa_jsp.java:157)
    at org.apache.jsp.formulario_005fempresa_jsp.access$1(formulario_005fempresa_jsp.java:138)
    at org.apache.jsp.formulario_005fempresa_jsp$Helper.invoke1(formulario_005fempresa_jsp.java:230)
    at org.apache.jsp.formulario_005fempresa_jsp$Helper.invoke(formulario_005fempresa_jsp.java:307)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.webplantillaformulario_tag.doTag(webplantillaformulario_tag.java:130)
    at org.apache.jsp.formulario_005fempresa_jsp._jspx_meth_t_005fplantillaformulario_005f0(formulario_005fempresa_jsp.java:112)
    at org.apache.jsp.formulario_005fempresa_jsp._jspService(formulario_005fempresa_jsp.java:85)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`
```

this is my class Comuna

```
public class Comuna {
int com_id;
int pro_id;
String com_nombre;
public Comuna(int com_id, int pro_id, String com_nombre) {
    super();
    this.com_id = com_id;
    this.pro_id = pro_id;
    this.com_nombre = com_nombre;
}
public Comuna(){

}
public int getCom_id() {
    return com_id;
}
public void setCom_id(int com_id) {
    this.com_id = com_id;
}
public int getPro_id() {
    return pro_id;
}
public void setPro_id(int pro_id) {
    this.pro_id = pro_id;
}
public String getCom_nombre() {
    return com_nombre;
}
public void setCom_nombre(String com_nombre) {
    this.com_nombre = com_nombre;
}
```

}

I think  this error has to do with the data type, but I cannot solve because because 
i'am newly learning, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get this error javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:The class `java.lang.String` does not have the property `com_id`

The problem is at below line where by mistake **a space is added after `${variable}`** that's why it's covered to `String` and `comunas` becomes of type `String` and `String` doesn't have any property `com_id`.

```
<c:forEach var="comunas" items="${variable} " >
```

Just *removing the extra ending space* will solve your problem.

---

There might be one more issue at below line to access the `Comunas` from `Conexion`.

```
<c:set var="variable" value="${Conexion.getComunas}"></c:set>
```

It should be

```
<c:set var="variable" value="${Conexion.getComunas()}"></c:set>
```

OR

```
<c:set var="variable" value="${Conexion.comunas}"></c:set>
```

OR

```
<c:set var="variable" value="${Conexion['comunas']}"></c:set>
```

Comment: thanks man, it was by a single space, now it works, but does not show me the info, now I'll see.

Comment: sorry a last question,now doesn't show anything, if i writte <c:set var="variable" value="${Conexion.getComunasasdf()}"></c:set> , getComunasasdf() method doesn't exist, my question is how i can know if the array comes empty?  i make this but whith <% %> and work's, for that reason i know the method is not bad.

Comment: It depends on how are you setting the attribute in the scope request,session or context. Look at the POJO classes again that proper getter method is present. Is this `getComunasasdf()` method present for the `Conexion` object.

Comment: Have you did something like `request.setAttribute("Conexion",conexionObject);` where `conexionObject` is of type `Conexion` and having getter method such as `getComusas()`. You can check the size using `<c:if test="${Conexion.getComunas().size()>0}">...</c:if>"` or `<c:if test="${Conexion.comunas.size()>0}">...</c:if>"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC, try adding the comuna arraylist object in your servlet's request object:

```
  request.setAttribute("comunaList", new Conexion().getComunas());
```

Then make a slight change to your JSTL loop code:

```
  <c:forEach var="comunas" items="${comunaList}">
```

Comment: This is a good tutorial for JSP and JSTL users: http://www.journaldev.com/2090/jstl-tutorial-with-examples-jstl-core-tags. Although I don't usually use "requestScope".

Comment: this response also serves me, but still did not make the controllers of the menu for pass that value for request, i'am litle confuse for use templates.  thanks for the tutorial.