# Can I use same requestScope more than one time in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I use requestScope item one time here. Here first foreach loop is working properly.

```
           <div class="list-group">
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Manufacturer List</a>
                                <c:forEach items="${requestScope.items}" var="item">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">${item.itemDesc} (  ${item.model}  ) </a>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </div>
```

I want to use same requestScope item again.

```
                            <c:forEach items="${requestScope.topitems}}" var="topitem">
                                <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                                    <h2>${topitem.itemDesc}</h2>
                                    <p>
                                        Manufacturer : ${topitem.manufacturer}
                                        Model : ${topitem.model}
                                        Part No : ${topitem.partNo}

                                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </c:forEach>
```

After using 2nd foreach loop, I got the following error.

> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:
>   The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'itemDesc'.
>   root cause
>
> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does
>   not have the property 'itemDesc'.

Comment: There seems to be an excess "}" in your 2nd for loop: items="${requestScope.topitems}}". Another thing I've learned recently is that the same error can occur if you add a space after your variable declaration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073693/jsp-error-for-not-correctly-use-jstl/24073828#24073828

Comment: @MichaelSanchez If you had put this as an answer thread could have been marked as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra `}` in your 2nd loop:

```
items="${requestScope.topitems}}"
```

The same error can occur if you add a space after your variable declaration [jsp - error for not correctly use JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073693/jsp-error-for-not-correctly-use-jstl)